# How to use ReadFile with multibyte codes

Tags: c, unicode, multibyte, widechar

How to use `ReadFile` to read a buffer as `wchar_t` array and then output it to the console

```
DWORD read_output()
{
    BOOL success = FALSE;
    DWORD dwRead;
    HANDLE handle = CreateFileW(L"data.txt",
                                GENERIC_READ,
                                0,
                                NULL,
                                3,
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                NULL);
    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        printf("Failed to open file\n");
    do
    {
        wchar_t buffer[128];
        success = ReadFile(handle, buffer, 128, &dwRead, NULL);
        wprintf(L"%s", buffer);
    } while(!success || dwRead == 0);
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    _setmode(fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    read_output();
}
```

This is the kind of output I get

```
 Ð¨Ð¸Ñ
      ÑÐ¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ.txt  Ø§Ù
```

what I should get

```
 Шифрование.txt  العربية.txt
```

if I remove `L"%s"` I get this

```
퀠킨톸톄킀킾킲킰킽킸⺵硴⁴�������⺩硴ੴ
```

can someone explain in detail how to read multibytes characters using `ReadFile`

Comment: You need to switch console output CP to Unicode UTF-16LE in order to output UNICODE symbols. I've developed a library to deal with this. Check [this](https://github.com/incoder1/IO/blob/master/examples/channels/main.cpp) and [this](https://github.com/incoder1/IO/blob/master/examples/iostreams/main.cpp) for a few examples.  As well as if don't wanting to link library and add additional dependencies - you can analyze library source and extract code for UNICODE console support (it is better to start from refactor branch then).

Comment: @VictorGubin those are c++ examples which extra functions from `console.hpp`

Comment: yes, mostly. As well as auto conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16LE  etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first output example indicates the file is encoded in UTF-8, so reading into `wchar_t` won't work.  Need to read into `char` then use `MultiByteToWideChar` to convert from UTF-8 to wide characters.  The characters read won't be null-terminated, so that needs to be added to the end of string before conversion.

Saving your "what I should get" in `data.txt` as UTF-8, this works:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD read_output()
{
    BOOL success = FALSE;
    DWORD dwRead;
    HANDLE handle = CreateFileW(L"data.txt", 
                                GENERIC_READ, 
                                0, 
                                NULL, 
                                3, 
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 
                                NULL);
    if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        printf("Failed to open file\n");

    char buffer[128];
    wchar_t buffer2[128];
    success = ReadFile(handle, buffer, sizeof buffer, &dwRead, NULL);
    buffer[dwRead] = 0;
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, buffer, dwRead, buffer2, _countof(buffer2));
    wprintf(L"%s\n", buffer2);
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    read_output();
}
```

Output to Windows command prompt as follows, but note the console font needs to contain glyphs for the characters to be displayed properly.  A copy/paste to SO shows the correct ones.

[image: actual console display]

```
Шифрование.txt  العربية.txt
```